# Route [confirm] not defined laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5

Recently I'm learning about laravel. So, I'm try to create a simple registration form with an email confirmation. Here is what I try to send the email. Here is my script

```
Mail::to($email)->send(new Confirmation([
                            'link' => URL::route('confirm', $email),
                            'username' => $username]));
```

But with my script above I get an error

> Route [confirm] not defined.

After I read the message, I'm trying to add `Route`, because the error say `route`

```
Route::get('/confirm/$email', 'Loginsite@confirm');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to name your route, so Laravel knows where to look when you're referring `URL::route('confirm')`

Try this:

```
Route::get('/confirm/$email', 'Loginsite@confirm')->name('confirm');
```

Edit: You should also pass your parameters into your route correctly, see https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/routing#required-parameters

The above should read:

```
Route::get('/confirm/{email}', 'Loginsite@confirm')->name('confirm');
```